# How to track the android application user's location

Tags: android, google-maps, push-notification, google-play-services, android-location

I have developed an android application for my university. There is a function to see all the university branches all over the island.

Now a new requirement has been raised which is to send a notification/sms/phone call to the user who has been downloaded our application from Google Play when he goes near a particular branch which the notification is saying there is a university branch near him.

How can I do this. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below GEOFENCING NOTIFICATIONS services it may be helpful to you.

http://www.plotprojects.com/?utm_expid=66248451-4.0dwsDCJKSxS_LWpWPiOk0Q.0&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2F

http://www.plotprojects.com/geofencing-3m/

This is test app link for this 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.plotprojects.retail.android.testapp